# Measuring Automation Test Step Execution Time

Tags: c#, automation, automated-tests, reporting, coded-ui-tests

I have 10 test methods each having some business functionality automated such as `Login(), CreateSomeRecord(), EditSomeRecord(), DeleteSomeRecord(), etc.`

I also have a HTML report that will capture what was done in a test method (capturing test steps basically). Something like this:

```
1. Enter Username: user01   User Entered Successfully   Pass
2. Enter Password: pass01   Pass Entered Successfully   Pass
3. Click Login button       Login successful            Pass
```

I basically construct that HTML file from code row by row.
Now, I want to add one more column to it to capture the duration - time taken to complete a particular step.

So, I am doing something like this:

```
// Initializing a new instance of the Stopwatch class
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
TimeSpan ts;
string elapsedTime;

//Username field
stopWatch.Start();
WpfEdit usrName = new WpfEdit(wpfWndObj);
#region Search Criteria
usrName.SearchProperties[WpfEdit.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "Usertxt";
usrName.WindowTitles.Add("My Test Application");
#endregion
Keyboard.SendKeys(usrName, usn); //usn has my username value in it
stopWatch.Stop();
ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
ts.Milliseconds / 10);
//Writing a new row into my HTML report
RptRowValueAdd(ReportDt, "", "Enter Username: " + usn, "Username Entered Successfully", "Pass", "", elapsedTime);
stopWatch.Reset();
```

**Contents of RptRowValueAdd function**

```
//DataTable tblObj is a dataset.
//I am writing the report into data-set first before writing it into a HTML file
public void RptRowValueAdd(DataTable tblObj, String TcName, String StepName, String ActRes, String Status, String ScrShtName, String TotalTimer = "", String BeginTimer = "", String EndTimer = "", String TestMethodName = "")
{
    tblObj.NewRow();
    tblObj.Rows.Add(ReportRowValue, TcName, StepName, ActRes, Status, ScrShtName,TotalTimer);
    ReportRowValue = ReportRowValue + 1;
}
```

This actually works but imagine the time involved in writing starting the stopwatch, stopping it, calculating the elapsed time and then resetting it. I need to do this for every single row I am writing into my HTML report file.

It is starting to become cumbersome when I think of doing this way for all 10 test methods.

Is there any better way to code this?

I am not looking for any profilers (ANTS) based solution. I know profilers are there for that purpose but I want to understand if there is a better way to handle what I am currently doing from the code.

Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: I would recommend you not run your tests like this.  It is too granular and requires specific ordering.  The code that sets up search properities should not be included in the timing.  You can then create a find method that performs stop watch timing. You'd have to create a wrapper method for each call that actually does something (ie, send keys, mouse click, Find ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I have pointed out in a few of your questions, I would not drive my tests like you have illustrated.  You are requiring test methods to execute in some particular order.  Further, you are requiring that the assertions be run in every case, even after they have been verified working.  For example, all your assertions in the Enter User Name method will run on every orchestration that involves setting the user name. This kind of defeats the point of testing the login by itself.  After the tests for setting the user name have passed, all other tests can just assume that it works.  **Depending on the assertions, it can increase the time dramatically to perform them every time.**

That said, I would create something separate that can orchestrate your tests.  This orchestration class can have timings associated with each step.  However, it is unclear how you are using the timings (if at all).

My blog covers this, but to hightlight what it could look like:

```
// orchestrates login user action
interface ILoginActions
{
    // logs in the user and returns a reference to the account settings page
    // which appears after successful login
    IAccountSettings Login(string username, string password);
}

public class LoginActions : ILoginActions
{
    public readonly ILoginPage loginPage;
    public LoginActions(ILoginPage loginPage)
    {
        this.loginPage = loginPage;
    }

    public IAccountSettings Login(string username, string password)
    {
        // the orchestrator does not typically need to make assertions,
        // and can assume that there are tests for Login actions
        stopWatch.Start();

        var model = 
        this.loginPage
            .Username.SetValue(username)
            .Password.SetValue(password)
            .Login.Click();

        stopWatch.Stop();

        log("Login Timing", stopWatch.Elapsed);

        return model;
    }
}
```

To reiterate, the above orchestration class exists on the presumption that there is a full set of tests for the login page that do not use the orchestration class.

The timings in the test methods them selves would have to be done either as you have already identified, or maybe some hybrid with @Mvarta's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think I am missing some details like what's happening in the RptRowValueAdd - how do you know the username was entered successfully and that the test passed? Regardless, maybe this approach will give you some ideas.

Have a class that represents data about each test:

```
public class TestDetails
{
    public string TestName { get; set; }
    public string ResultDescription { get; set; }
    public Result TestResult { get; set; }
    public string ElapsedTime { get; set; }

    public TestDetails(string testName, string resultDescription, Result result, string elapsedTime)
    {
        ResultDescription = resultDescription;
        TestResult = result;
        ElapsedTime = elapsedTime;
    }

    public enum Result
    {
        Pass,
        Fail
        // etc
    }
}
```

Then, create a method which takes a test as an action parameter and returns the details of the test.

```
    public static TestDetails RunTest(Action testMethod)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        TimeSpan ts;
        string elapsedTime;
        sw.Start();
        testMethod.Invoke();
        sw.Stop();
        ts = sw.Elapsed;
        elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
        ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
        ts.Milliseconds / 10);

        return new TestDetails("Enter username: ", "Username entered Successfully", TestDetails.Result.Pass, elapsedTime);
    }
```

To use these, you can create a list of action methods, to which you can add all of your tests and call them in a foreach:

```
        var tests = new List<Action>
        (
            Login,
            CreateSomeRecord,
            EditSomeRecord,
            DeleteSomeRecord
        );

        foreach (var test in tests)
        {
            var testDetails = RunTest(test);
            RptRowValueAdd(ReportDt, "", testDetails.TestName, testDetails.ResultDescription, testDetails.TestResult.ToString(), testDetails.ElapsedTime);
        }
```

I hope I haven't misunderstood you.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated my question to include the definition of RptRowValueAdd function. I am still going through your answer to understand it better :)

Comment: Ok... So, if I understand right, that for loop is executed once for one test method. I want it to write multiple times in a test method. For example, if you see my code in original post, the "Login" is just one test method and it has multiple test steps - 1. Enter username 2. Enter Password, 3. Click Login button, 4. Check if Login is successful (by asserting title bar). How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Hi again. If the code you've listed is just one step in the Login() test, maybe you can break each step into it's own method, then add them to the List<Action>, and iterate over that. Your results will represent one test with multiple steps.

Comment: Sounds more like BDD framework. I mean every single action could be written as a method. For example, EnterValue (can take the parameters as control name and string to enter), ClickButton (can take control name and click method). Kinda makes sense i guess. Thank you! Still need to think through it.

Comment: This approach is an improvement, but I would still consider these methods to be part of some external model.  I have some blog posts about this:  http://michaelpavlakcoding.blogspot.com/2016/06/decomposing-page-objects.html